# JS use SQL select on dropbox

Tags: javascript, sql, vb.net, select, dropbox

I have a page with a dropbox and values. Now I want to select a few more values depending on the selected value of the dropbox. The values are defined in a SQL database.

Section on the page with the dropbox:

```
<div class="span6 form-group">
<label for="SELECTING_PRODUCT">Product:</label>
<select id="SELECTING_PRODUCT" name='productname' style="width: 100%;" onmouseup="RunValidate()"/>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select offer</option>
        <option value="T1001">Radio</option>
        <option value="D4002">Televison</option>
        <option value="F8013">Car</option>
        <option value="Y9104">Fridge</option>
</select>
   </div>
```

And the SQL table [dbo].[product_info]

```
 ID, prodctcode, productname, ext_info, price
 1, D4002, Television, a nice 32" TV, 400
 2, F8013, Car, Used Ford Mustang, 28.000
 3, T1001, Radio, Perfect sound all around, 250
 4, Y9104, Fridge, cold wehenever you need it, 699
```

How can I select the values "ext_info" and "price" and use them later on while making a sort of billing review based on the selected value.
 Note: Only one item can be selected in the dropbox.

So I want to pickup the extra values from the SQL table that belongs to the option the user selects. And the extra values have to be displayed later on.

Comment: What Server Side Language are you using and How are you connecting to the SQL Database ? 
You would have to create an API Endpoint to interface directly with your JS file. 
The API Endpoint would fetch the value submitted by the JS File, Query The SQL Database with the Value and Return the Response from the Query to the JS Fille.
Update Your Question with More Code / Example of what you have done.

Comment: Standard HTML & CSS, the connection is established in an ASP.NET visual basic file. For the remaing part of the page I only use HTML and JavaScript

Comment: Then Please Update Your Question. are you asking for how to pick up the value the user selected with JavaScript OR are you asking for how to Structure an SQL query with ASP.NET ?

Comment: This is a Visual Basic question, you'll have more luck tagging that language